# GoogleCloud VertexAI tutorial: FailedPrecondition: 400 <model> is not exportable from BigQueryML

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-vertex-ai

When trying to run this tutorial https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/official/bigquery_ml/bqml-online-prediction.ipynb (also available when you create a VertexAI workbench "tutorials/vertex_samples/official/bigquery_ml/bqml-online-prediction.ipynb")
, this error happens:

```
_InactiveRpcError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
     56         try:
---> 57             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     58         except grpc.RpcError as exc:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py in __call__(self, request, timeout, metadata, credentials, wait_for_ready, compression)
    945                                       wait_for_ready, compression)
--> 946         return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
    947 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py in _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, with_call, deadline)
    848     else:
--> 849         raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
    850 

_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION
    details = "Model projects/<some_number>/locations/europe-west2/models/plans_copy_very_dumb_model@2 is not exportable from BigQueryML."
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:74.125.140.95:443 {created_time:"2022-11-22T17:20:11.595548603+00:00", grpc_status:9, grpc_message:"Model projects/<some_number>/locations/europe-west2/models/plans_copy_very_dumb_model@2 is not exportable from BigQueryML."}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

FailedPrecondition                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_1/3081084994.py in <module>
      1 #deploying the model to the endpoint may take 10-15 minutes
----> 2 model.deploy(endpoint=endpoint)

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/models.py in deploy(self, endpoint, deployed_model_display_name, traffic_percentage, traffic_split, machine_type, min_replica_count, max_replica_count, accelerator_type, accelerator_count, service_account, explanation_metadata, explanation_parameters, metadata, encryption_spec_key_name, network, sync, deploy_request_timeout, autoscaling_target_cpu_utilization, autoscaling_target_accelerator_duty_cycle)
   3316             deploy_request_timeout=deploy_request_timeout,
   3317             autoscaling_target_cpu_utilization=autoscaling_target_cpu_utilization,
-> 3318             autoscaling_target_accelerator_duty_cycle=autoscaling_target_accelerator_duty_cycle,
   3319         )
   3320 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/base.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    808                 if self:
    809                     VertexAiResourceNounWithFutureManager.wait(self)
--> 810                 return method(*args, **kwargs)
    811 
    812             # callbacks to call within the Future (in same Thread)

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/models.py in _deploy(self, endpoint, deployed_model_display_name, traffic_percentage, traffic_split, machine_type, min_replica_count, max_replica_count, accelerator_type, accelerator_count, service_account, explanation_metadata, explanation_parameters, metadata, encryption_spec_key_name, network, sync, deploy_request_timeout, autoscaling_target_cpu_utilization, autoscaling_target_accelerator_duty_cycle)
   3489             deploy_request_timeout=deploy_request_timeout,
   3490             autoscaling_target_cpu_utilization=autoscaling_target_cpu_utilization,
-> 3491             autoscaling_target_accelerator_duty_cycle=autoscaling_target_accelerator_duty_cycle,
   3492         )
   3493 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/models.py in _deploy_call(cls, api_client, endpoint_resource_name, model, endpoint_resource_traffic_split, network, deployed_model_display_name, traffic_percentage, traffic_split, machine_type, min_replica_count, max_replica_count, accelerator_type, accelerator_count, service_account, explanation_metadata, explanation_parameters, metadata, deploy_request_timeout, autoscaling_target_cpu_utilization, autoscaling_target_accelerator_duty_cycle)
   1232             traffic_split=traffic_split,
   1233             metadata=metadata,
-> 1234             timeout=deploy_request_timeout,
   1235         )
   1236 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1/services/endpoint_service/client.py in deploy_model(self, request, endpoint, deployed_model, traffic_split, retry, timeout, metadata)
   1261             retry=retry,
   1262             timeout=timeout,
-> 1263             metadata=metadata,
   1264         )
   1265 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py in __call__(self, timeout, retry, *args, **kwargs)
    152             kwargs["metadata"] = metadata
    153 
--> 154         return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
    155 
    156 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
     57             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     58         except grpc.RpcError as exc:
---> 59             raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
     60 
     61     return error_remapped_callable

FailedPrecondition: 400 Model projects/<some_number>/locations/europe-west2/models/plans_copy_very_dumb_model@2 is not exportable from BigQueryML.
Is it maybe because of region/location mismatches/conflicts?
```

The error happens in the "Deploy model to Vertex endpoint" step, in which you run `model.deploy(endpoint=endpoint)`

I'm running the script exclusively on Google Cloud Console VertexAI Workbench.

The region of the Workbench machine is `europe-west1`.

The BigQuery dataset, the VertexAI model that is created and stored in the registry during the tutorial, and the VertexAI endpoint are in `europe-west2`

What am I doing wrong?

#### Very important note:

I cannot follow the original tutorial, because I get an error when creating the model (step "Train a classification model using BigQuery ML"):
`NotFound: 404 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<some_name>/jobs?prettyPrint=false: Not found: Dataset <some_name>:ga4_churnprediction was not found in location US`

To work around it, I'm using a `europe-west2` dataset, and a very dummy model:

```
BQML_MODEL_NAME = f"plans_copy_very_dumb_model"

sql_train_model_bqml = f"""
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL {BQ_DATASET_NAME}.{BQML_MODEL_NAME}    
OPTIONS(
  MODEL_TYPE="LOGISTIC_REG",
  input_label_cols=["id"], -- instead of setting the proper labels as in the tutorial
  model_registry="vertex_ai",
  vertex_ai_model_version_aliases=['logistic_reg', 'experimental']
) AS

SELECT
  *
FROM
  `<some_name>.mongo_atlas_dev.plans_copy` -- instead of fetching data from "bqmlpublic.demo_ga4churnprediction.training_data"
"""

print(sql_train_model_bqml)

run_bq_query(sql_train_model_bqml)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a warning about regions. Perhaps it should work across regions but a practical way forward would be to first get everything working in one region. So either everything in `eu-west-1` or everything in `eu-west-2`.